# Styling PHP errors or messages from a separate file

Tags: php, html, css, formatting

I have a simple login form and a separate php file that contain error message functions etc (i.e. "password field was empty" etc).

The problem is when the error is triggered from the form it does not style the error message the same as the form. The error appears unformatted at the bottom of the page.

I want to be able to apply the forms CSS to the php messages that are in the separate file.

This is a code snippet from the separate PHP file:

```
// check login form contents
        if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
```

I want to be able to place these error message inside the div elements of my form. At present they end up unformatted at the bottom of the page.

I have tried just enclosing the PHP in the separate file in the same div tags that the form has but it does not work.

Hope this makes some sense.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post more code, but still pertinent to this problem, form markup and where its submitted

Answer (score 1):

just create a custom config file

config.php

```
$_SESSION['err_uname_req'] = "<font color='red'>Username Required</font>";
$_SESSION['err_pword_req'] = "<font color='red'>Password Required</font>";
...
```

in your sample form:

```
session_start();

//call config.php

if($_POST['username'] == "")//or any approach to display the error
{
    echo $_SESSION['err_username_req'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give index to your error store them in session. dont forget to start session at the top
in both file

```
if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
            $this->errors['user_name'] = "Username field was empty.";
            $this->_SESSION['first']=$this->errors['user_name'];

        } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
            $this->errors['user_password'] = "Password field was empty.";
            $this->_SESSION['second']=$this->errors['user_password'];
```

in another file

```
session_start();//start the session
<div id="first_error">$_SESSION['first']</div>
<div id="second_error">$_SESSION['second']</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe session storage is the place for error notifications, they should be generated and displayed within the one script execution.

Comment: @Scuzzy he said he want in different page. Thats why i stored them in session. other wise you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Format the desired divs in one page and at the top of the page do an include or required function.  Place the error messages in variables and then echo the variables inside the div.  You don't need sessions to do this, thing is, you'll have to create global variables to get their data from inside the if statement.  For example.

**First page.**

```
global $errorname;
global $errorpass;
if(empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
    $this->errors['user_name'] = "Username field was empty.";
    $errorname =  $this->errors['user_name'];
}
elseif(empty($_POST['user_password'])){
    $this->errors['password'] = "Password field was empty.";
    $errorpass = $this->errors['password']
}
```

**Second page**

```
<?php include('page1.php'); ?>
<div id="first_error"><?php echo $errorname; ?></div>
```